# How do I know UIDevice model in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uidevice

I'd like to get precise device model (e.g. iPad 3) in MonoTouch.
I've seen it [done in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1108859/458193) but I haven't figured out the correct P/Invokes yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took this from a few places and changed it to what I needed, so I can't take full credit for it. It really stinks to have an enum that has to be updated, but oh well.

But this is what I have:

```cs
public static class DeviceHelper
{
    public const string HardwareProperty = "hw.machine";
    public static readonly string PLATFORM;

    public static bool IsTall
    {
        get
        {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom
                == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
                    && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
                    * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale >= 1136;
        }
    }

    [DllImport(MonoTouch.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
    static internal extern int sysctlbyname([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property, IntPtr output, IntPtr oldLen, IntPtr newp, uint newlen);

    static DeviceHelper ()
    {
        var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
        sysctlbyname(HardwareProperty, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);

        var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        sysctlbyname(HardwareProperty, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        var hardwareStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);

        var ret = HardwareVersion.Unknown;

        if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,2")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3G;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone2,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3GS;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone3,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone4;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone3,3")
            ret = HardwareVersion.VerizoniPhone4;
        else if(hardwareStr == "iPhone4,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone4S;
        else if(hardwareStr == "iPhone 5,1" || hardwareStr == "iPhone 5,2")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone5;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad1,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2WIFI;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,2")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2GSM;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,3")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2CDMA;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,4")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2WIFI24;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3WIFI;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,2")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3GSM;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,3")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3CDMA;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPod1,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPod1G;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPod2,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPod2G;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPod3,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPod3G;
        else if (hardwareStr == "iPod4,1")
            ret = HardwareVersion.iPod4G;
        else if (hardwareStr == "i386" || hardwareStr=="x86_64") {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model.Contains("iPhone"))
                ret = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 || UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 ? HardwareVersion.iPhone4Simulator : HardwareVersion.iPhoneSimulator;
            else
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPadSimulator;
        }

        if(ret == HardwareVersion.Unknown)
            PLATFORM = hardwareStr;
        else
            PLATFORM = ret.ToString();
    }

    public enum HardwareVersion {
        iPhone,
        iPhone3G,
        iPhone3GS,
        iPhone4,
        VerizoniPhone4,
        iPhone4S,
        iPhone5,
        iPod1G,
        iPod2G,
        iPod3G,
        iPod4G,
        iPad,
        iPad2WIFI,
        iPad2WIFI24,
        iPad2GSM,
        iPad2CDMA,
        iPad3WIFI,
        iPad3GSM,
        iPad3CDMA,
        iPhoneSimulator,
        iPhone4Simulator,
        iPadSimulator,
        Unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, this seems more thought out than my solution (though the core is the same). Also, using enum is good. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Do you know the `MonoTouch.Constants.SystemLibrary` equivalent in latest `Xamarion.iOS`. I can't find that class for a DllImport in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494590/458193) as a basis.
I'm not sure this is the shortest way, but it works.

```
[DllImport ("libc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int sysctlbyname (string name, StringBuilder value, ref IntPtr length, IntPtr newp, IntPtr newlen);

public static string GetDeviceName (this UIDevice device)
{
    IntPtr size = (IntPtr) 8;
    var sb = new StringBuilder ();

    string param = "hw.machine";
    sysctlbyname (param, sb, ref size, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) 0);

    return sb.ToString ();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing 8 as the length, since some identifiers will be longer than that, in which case you get null back for your string. Instead, you should call sysctlbyname while passing a null value first. This will cause size to be updated with the correct length, after which you can call it again to obtain the entire identifier.